# Remote procedure call: how to declare two versions of same program in a XDR file

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, rpc

I am writing a program which makes a RPC to print a message that I send as a parameter to the remote function. The remote function is not supposed to return anything, however just out of curiosity I have designed the remote function to return an integer.

Anyways, everything worked fine and I was able to print a message remotely. Now I am trying to create two versions of a program in XDR file (Just curious!!!) but its not working out for me.

here is my new XDR file

```
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Documents/C/DS/RPC$ cat spec.x 
program MSGPROG{

    version PRINTMSGVERSION{
        int PRINTMSG(string) = 1;
    } = 1;

    version PRINTMSGVERSION{
        int PRINTMSG(string) = 1;
    } = 2;

} = 0x2000001;
```

Here is the server code:

```
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Documents/C/DS/RPC$ cat server.c 
#include<stdio.h>
#include "spec.h"

int *printmsg_1_svc(char **msg,struct svc_req * sr){
    static int ret;

    printf("version = 1--%s\n",*msg);
    ret = 1;
    return &ret;    
}

int *printmsg_2_svc(char **msg,struct svc_req * sr){
    static int ret;

    printf("version = 2--%s\n",*msg);
    ret = 1;
    return &ret;    
}
```

Here are the errors that I get at compile time:

```
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Documents/C/DS/RPC$ rpcgen -C spec.x
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Documents/C/DS/RPC$ gcc server.c spec_svc.c -o ani_server -lnsl
In file included from server.c:2:
spec.h:32: warning: "PRINTMSGVERSION" redefined
spec.h:18: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from spec_svc.c:6:
spec.h:32: warning: "PRINTMSGVERSION" redefined
spec.h:18: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

So the error is coming because I am not able to figure out how to declare two versions of a program in XDR file. Thanks a lot for reading my post. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I just checked the "spec.h" file. rpcgen has done `#define PRINTMSGVERSION 1`. it then does `#define PRINTMSGVERSION 2`. So if I declare another version of the program with same name but different version number (like I did above) things won't work out for me. One can not #define a variable twice without #undef ing it.
This way there is no point in giving version number because there would be no way I would be able to declare a program with same name but different version number.


Any suggestions ?

Comment: this my new updated spec.x file

`program MSGPROG{

 version PRINTMSGVERSION{
  int PRINTMSG(string) = 1;
 } = 1;
 
 version PRINTMSGVERSION_NEW{
  int PRINTMSG(string) = 1;
 } = 2;

} = 0x2000001;`

but now because of this everytime my client wants to connect to server it has to create two different handles to connect to two different versions of the same program. 
BUT ya! ya! THAT IS HOW "`clnt_create(..)`" function is defined.

Comment: I still can not understand the significance of VERSION NUMBER. If you find me wrong somewhere please enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A version name cannot occur more than once within the scope of a
   program definition. Nor can a version number occur more than once
   within the scope of a program definition." - [RFC 1057](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1057.txt)

You simply have to give the version string distinct names, e.g.:

```
program MSGPROG{

    version PRINTMSGVERSION_1 {
        int PRINTMSG(string) = 1;
    } = 1;

    version PRINTMSGVERSION_2{
        int PRINTMSG(string) = 1;
    } = 2;

} = 0x2000001;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what is the point in giving version numbers if I can distinguish by names. 
I mean if the names are same and version numbers are different then RPCGEN could have internally given them different names by appending the version numbers at the end instead of making it the job of the programmer to distinguish between the versions by giving different names and different versions.

Comment: Your .x files are specification for the RPC protocol, it gives you full control over the fundamentals (such as a program version number). Every vendor of the rpcgen program had to use the same algorithm to invent a version numer if it should be autogenerated, and you'd have little chance of being able to reverse engineer an existing protocol that didn't have a .x file to begin with.  Perhaps rpcgen could have appended the version in the .define, but it doesn't, it leaves it up to you, which has some pros and some cons.